# How to remove anything character after the part of link from string?

Tags: php, string

I have make a try like this:

```
$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar";
echo $string = substr($string, 0, strpos(strrev($string), "-/(0-9+)")-13);
```

and the output work :

```
localhost/product/-/123456 cause this just for above link with 13 character after /-/123456
```

How to remove all? i try

```
$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar";
echo $string = substr($string, 0, strpos(strrev($string), "-/(0-9+)")-(.*));
```

not work and error sintax.

and i try

```
$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar";
echo $string = substr($string, 0, strpos(strrev($string), "-/(0-9+)")-999);
```

the output is empty..

Comment: whats your desire output??

Comment: if i try strpos(strrev($string), "-/(0-9+)")-13); and work! like here http://ideone.com/ceMbh5  how about for long character? and to remove anything after strpos(strrev($string), "-/(0-9+)")?);

Comment: i want the out put just localhost/product/-/123456 and remove all after that..

Comment: strpos does not support regex, it works because it finds the position of `-/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume there are no number  after `localhost/product/-/123456`, then I will just trim it with below

```
$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar";
echo rtrim($string, "a..zA..Z-"); // localhost/product/-/123456
```

Another non-regex version, but require 5.3.0+

```
$str = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar-1-pdf/";
echo dirname($str) . "/" . strstr(basename($str), "-", true); //localhost/product/-/123456
```

Heres a more flexibility way but involve in regex

```
$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar";

echo preg_replace("/^([^?]*-\/\d+)([^?]*)/", "$1", $string);
// localhost/product/-/123456

$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar-1-pdf/";
echo preg_replace("/^([^?]*-\/\d+)([^?]*)/", "$1", $string); 
// localhost/product/-/123456
```

This should match capture everything up to the number and remove everything afterward

[regex101: localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar](https://regex101.com/r/zL2pD0/1)

[regex101: localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar-1-pdf/](https://regex101.com/r/zL2pD0/2)

Comment: nice, how I did not think on that!

Comment: Thanks Andrew and CJ Nimes this work to.. nice. i am happy!! ;()

Comment: @netboy78, if the provided solution worked, please upvote the answer to close the question.

Comment: @CJNimes this only trim if the letter Aa to Zz and dash after the number, if there are other chars than that, it wont work as expected..

Comment: @Andrew how about if $string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar-1-pdf" ? This is what you mean? or localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar-1-pdf/

Comment: @netboy78 yes, then you would want to use the regex one since it involve more complexity on string manipulation

Answer (score 1):

Not a one-liner, but this will do the trick:

```
$string = "localhost/product/-/123456-Ebook-Guitar";

// explode by "/"
$array1 = explode('/', $string);

// take the last element
$last = array_pop($array1);

// explode by "-"
$array2 = explode('-', $last);

// and finally, concatenate only what we want
$result = implode('/', $array1) . '/' . $array2[0];

// $result ---> "localhost/product/-/123456"
```

Comment: Thanks You so much CJ Nimes.. I am forgot to echo ($result); that result ;) now is work!! Thanks A Lot!! http://ideone.com/IWjScu